# Initialization failed for Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid a367dc5f-241c-4fde-bfd0-36eb8c1186ed) service to namenode/172.29.0.3:8020. Exiting

Tags: docker, hadoop, hdfs

I raise the hadoop cluster to docker, after the first launch everything works stably, but as soon as I restart the cluster, then my data nodes start for a few seconds and stop working. I am getting an error in the logs. How to fix it?

```
2023-08-17 10:25:48 2023-08-17 07:25:48 ERROR DataNode:903 - Initialization failed for Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid 11f11079-a4eb-4e8b-9023-3b14351c7e85) service to namenode/172.29.0.2:8020. Exiting. 
2023-08-17 10:25:48 java.io.IOException: All specified directories have failed to load.
2023-08-17 10:25:48     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:562)
2023-08-17 10:25:48     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initStorage(DataNode.java:2059)
2023-08-17 10:25:48     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initBlockPool(DataNode.java:1995)
2023-08-17 10:25:48     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPOfferService.verifyAndSetNamespaceInfo(BPOfferService.java:394)
2023-08-17 10:25:48     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.connectToNNAndHandshake(BPServiceActor.java:312)
2023-08-17 10:25:48     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.run(BPServiceActor.java:891)
2023-08-17 10:25:48     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2023-08-17 10:25:48 2023-08-17 07:25:48 WARN  DataNode:931 - Ending block pool service for: Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid 11f11079-a4eb-4e8b-9023-3b14351c7e85) service to namenode/172.29.0.2:8020
2023-08-17 10:25:48 2023-08-17 07:25:48 INFO  DataNode:102 - Removed Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid 11f11079-a4eb-4e8b-9023-3b14351c7e85)
2023-08-17 10:25:50 2023-08-17 07:25:50 WARN  DataNode:3256 - Exiting Datanode
2023-08-17 10:25:50 2023-08-17 07:25:50 INFO  DataNode:51 - SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
2023-08-17 10:25:50 /************************************************************
2023-08-17 10:25:50 SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at db3b2eb8c96c/172.29.0.5
2023-08-17 10:25:50 ************************************************************
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.3.6"
services:
   namenode:
      image: apache/hadoop:3.3.6
      hostname: namenode
      command: ["hdfs", "namenode"]
      ports:
        - 9870:9870
      env_file:
        - ./config
      environment:
          ENSURE_NAMENODE_DIR: "/tmp/hadoop-root/dfs/name"
   datanode1:
      image: apache/hadoop:3.3.6
      command: ["hdfs", "datanode"]
      env_file:
        - ./config
   datanode2:
      image: apache/hadoop:3.3.6
      command: ["hdfs", "datanode"]
      env_file:
        - ./config  
   resourcemanager:
      image: apache/hadoop:3.3.6
      hostname: resourcemanager
      command: ["yarn", "resourcemanager"]
      ports:
         - 8088:8088
      env_file:
        - ./config
      volumes:
        - ./test.sh:/opt/test.sh
   nodemanager:
      image: apache/hadoop:3.3.6
      command: ["yarn", "nodemanager"]
      env_file:
        - ./config
```

config

```
CORE-SITE.XML_fs.default.name=hdfs://namenode
CORE-SITE.XML_fs.defaultFS=hdfs://namenode
HDFS-SITE.XML_dfs.namenode.rpc-address=namenode:8020
HDFS-SITE.XML_dfs.replication=1
MAPRED-SITE.XML_mapreduce.framework.name=yarn
MAPRED-SITE.XML_yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env=HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
MAPRED-SITE.XML_mapreduce.map.env=HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
MAPRED-SITE.XML_mapreduce.reduce.env=HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
YARN-SITE.XML_yarn.resourcemanager.hostname=resourcemanager
YARN-SITE.XML_yarn.nodemanager.pmem-check-enabled=false
YARN-SITE.XML_yarn.nodemanager.delete.debug-delay-sec=600
YARN-SITE.XML_yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled=false
YARN-SITE.XML_yarn.nodemanager.aux-services=mapreduce_shuffle
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-applications=10000
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent=0.1
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DefaultResourceCalculator
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.queues=default
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.capacity=100
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.user-limit-factor=1
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.maximum-capacity=100
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.state=RUNNING
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.acl_submit_applications=*
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.acl_administer_queue=*
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.node-locality-delay=40
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.queue-mappings=
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.queue-mappings-override.enable=false
```

I tried the solution - [Initialization failed for Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33987253/initialization-failed-for-block-pool-registering-datanode-uuid-unassigned). It did not help. I can't find any other solutions. As I understand it, the problem is that after restarting the cluster, the clusterid in the data node is different from the name node. Checked it, it is. The solution above doesn't help.

Comment: Please show your errors, configs and files as text, not images

Comment: I did it. It would be great if you can help.

Comment: I've not worked with Hadoop in years, but [this project had worked for me](https://github.com/OneCricketeer/docker-stacks/blob/master/hadoop-spark/docker-compose.yml). You don't need YARN to run Mapreduce/Spark code locally. That will only resource-constrain any code by running small JVM conatiners in an already constrained container (the nodemanager). Nor do you really need HDFS since accessing local disk will work fine